# Retrieve all the contact from contact in ng-cordova ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to retrieve all the contact from iPhone using ng-cordova and ionic. And I want to display all contact where user can choose the contact

Comment: Would you be able to show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great blogpost about the case you are asking about:
http://calendee.com/2014/07/17/cordova-contacts-plugin-with-ionic-framework/